# Blender Crashes When Being Started

Tags: error

I used Blender for a while then I stopped using it a few months back and yesterday when I tried running it, it crashed and gave me this error:

```
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

These is what I tried:
-Uninstalling then installing the newest version
-Uninstalling again then installing an older version
-Deleted every registry file and folder related to Blender
-Reinstalled 50 times
-Restarted my PC 10 times
-Installed Python 10 times (before and after Blender)

Non of this works and there I can't find the explanation why, I searched online but can't find the same case happening to someone else.

EDIT: All drivers are up-to-date!

Comment: have you seen this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77857/error-al-lib-updatedeviceparams-failed-to-set-44100hz-got-48000hz-instead-wh?

Comment: @m.ardito it is not the top line that is the problem but the "Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION"

Comment: Try the zip version of blender. just unzip and run, no install or external python needed.

Comment: Okay I'll try the zip thing

Comment: Didn't work ...

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out, just downloaded a file called "opengl32.dll" and put it in the Blender directory

Comment: That likely indicates that there is something messed up with your graphics.  See the `opengl32.dll` makes blender do all graphics processing (drawing blender' ui, the 3D view, and rendering) on the cpu. What graphics card do you have?

Comment: I have a GTX 750 Ti but it's the 1GB version

Comment: Blender is lagging a lot now

Comment: See if https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/61749/2217 helps.

Comment: My GPU driver is updated

Answer (score 0):

**Downgrading blender** was the only thing which worked in my case.

(Updating blender and updating graphics card, and look if the blender install is clean like described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61749/how-do-i-fix-exception-access-violation-error-on-startup/99554#99554) didn't work for me)