# Blender crashes on startup windows 10

Tags: windows, error

I installed the blender after a fresh installation of windows 10. I have all the drivers installed. I have GTX 1060 graphics card. After running the blender, the console blinks and the program does not run. I text In the console blender.exe -d I have such error:

```
 found bundled python: C: \ Program Files \ Blender Foundation \ Blender \ 2.79 \ 
 pythonError: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION.
```

I'm trying install 2.79a version but 2.79 dosnt run too. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you updated the drivers? There's some suggestions in this thread that might help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61749/how-do-i-fix-exception-access-violation-error-on-startup

Comment: Are you installing from the installer or the zip? In either case, what happens it you try the other?

Answer (score 3):

Set this Environment Variable on Windows:
Variable: CYCLES_OPENCL_TEST
Value: NONE

1. On your Desktop, right click on the `This PC` icon and select `Properties`
2. Select `Advanced system settings` from the list on the left
3. Select `Environmental Variables` at the bottom
4. Under `System Variables`, click `New...`
5. `Variable Name:` **CYCLES_OPENCL_TEST**
6. `Value:` **NONE**
7. Click `Ok` several times to set the variable and close the settings windows
8. Start Blender without error

Comment: Hi. I think it would be helpful to explain *how* the user should test those variables.

Comment: I don't understand. There is nothing to test here.

Comment: I think I meant to say 'set' instead of 'test'. My point is that you haven't told the user *how* to set the environment variable.

Comment: How to set windows variables can be found googling for it. It's publicly available knowledge.

Comment: Wow, a downvote because i did not exactly do what you want? That's low.

Comment: Not because you didn't do exactly what I want, but because I genuinely think, without the additional information I mentioned, this answer isn't very useful. Instead of immediately down-voting, I suggested what could be improved. When I saw that the answer wasn't going to improve, I voted.

Comment: So where does this end? Do i have to explain how to install windows? Configure a computer? Install blender?
Setting up windows environment variables is a "windows feature" and has nothing to do with Blender. Each Version of Windows even has different approaches to this. This is just arbitrary mockery of new users because you don't get what you want.

Comment: If you would like to get the opinion of other users on this you can ask a question on the Blender Meta site: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I'm fine with my answer so I don't see the point.

Comment: THANK YOU I WORKED !!!!