# Why is the latest version of Blender not working when I meet the minimum requirements?

Tags: versions

[image: Command prompt output]

[image]

When I run blender from the command prompt, the window comes up, closes, and this is the output:

Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Address: 0x000000006CA42D7B

Module: atio6axx.dll

Thread: 000023bc

Blender immediately closes as soon as it is opened, even though my computer meets the minimum requirements. I currently have to run the 32 bit version (even though my OS is 64 bit), which means I am stuck on 2.8 and a lot of the tutorials I try to follow don't work. I don't have enough money to upgrade my PC.

The second picture is what happens when it just boots regularly. Again, it immediately closes.

GPU: AMD FirePro M2000 (I can provide further details if necessary, I just really want to be able to run Blender 2.9)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix Exception Access Violation error on startup?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61749/how-do-i-fix-exception-access-violation-error-on-startup)

Comment: No it doesn't. I've already tried updating drivers and removing other blender installations.

Comment: 2.80 is the latest to support 32 bit, From 2.81 and up is 64 bits only

Comment: What is GPU exactly, model number, release year? Note that the fact GPU has OpenGL 3.3 version does not mean anything at all, it can also be not supported. Provide more information or better refer to wiki page from blender.org downloads section for supported cards' names

Comment: I can't tell how it turns out that you try to run 2.92 but mention that you need to use 32-bit version and are stuck on 2.8, since you know that 2.81+ versions don't support 32-bit. Anyway as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units M2000 is Terascale 2 architecture and is deprecated as of 2.91. I'd say it's not supported even for 2.82 but who knows, you might try that. If you want to use latest versions you have to find newer hardware - that's the only way

Comment: Gosh dang it. I was really hoping I didn't have to get a new computer. Thank you though! (Mainly I just wanted to be able to denoise lol)

Comment: Actually, thank you! I tried installing blender 2.81, and it works without me doing anything! Looks like you were right!

Answer (score 1):

atio6axx.dll is AMD graphics card related. [It's been addressed before.](https://developer.blender.org/T71463) Are you certain that your graphics card is both up to date with its drivers, and actively still supported for 2.80?